# Returning the list of elements occurring in just one list - SML

Tags: list, sml

If L1 = [1,2,3,4,5] and L2 [4,5,6,7,8], I want to return [1,2,3,5,7,8] which are the elements occurring in one list only. I already wrote a function returning the list of items occurring in both lists.

```
fun exists x nil = false | exists x (h::t) = (x = h) orelse (exists x t);

fun listAnd _ [] = []
  | listAnd [] _ = []
  | listAnd (x::xs) ys = if exists x ys  then x::(listAnd xs ys) 
else listAnd xs ys
```

The list I am looking for should be given by L1@L2 - (ListAnd L1 L2). I also found functions that delete an element and remove Duplicates. I made several attempts at changing the remDup function slightly so that it will leave no trace of ANY items that occured more than once. Could not get it working. I am not sure how to use and combine all those functions to make it work.

```
fun delete A nil = nil
| delete A (B::R) = if (A=B) then (delete A R) else (B::(delete A R));

fun remDups nil = nil
| remDups (A::R) = (A::(remDups (delete A R)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a `diff` function where `diff xs ys` returns all elements in `xs` but not in `ys`, you can implement `listOr` function easily:

```
fun listOr xs ys = diff (xs@ys) (listAnd xs ys)
```

The `diff` function can be written similarly to `listAnd`:

```
fun diff xs [] = xs
  | diff [] _ = []
  | diff (x::xs) ys = if exists x ys  
                      then diff xs ys 
                      else x::(diff xs ys)
```